# Install an UWP app, from another UWP app on WinIoT Core

Tags: uwp, lifecycle, launch, appx

I'm new in UWP App development and was watching some Microsoft Education Videos about lifecycle and UWP apps. Now I question, if it is possible to do, what I would like to do. Maybe you can help me to answer some questions:

1.) Is it possible to install an XY.appx from my Launcher app? (Launcher detects an xy.appx on a USB stick and installs this app).

2.) If my Launcher app is a UWP UI app, it would be possible to start another application (already installed one) by URI activation. As far as I understand, this is only possible as UI app (not as background service)?

3.) Is it possible to close another app out of my Launcher app? (I guess no, but it would be nice, if the launcher could kill what was started by the Launcher app).

4.) If the Launcher app is a UI app and would start another UI app, then the Launcher app gets suspended. Is there any possibility to get any app to app communication between a background service (or my new foreground app) and the suspended Launcher?

What I aim to implement is a Launcher which checks for an inserted USB stick and installs (and starts) what ever is on that stick or starts another "default" app. How could I solve it?

Thanks
Schaf

Comment: Wow, you asked several question on one thread, I suggest that you'd better ask one question on one thread. I believe there will be many community members will be happy to help u.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) Is it possible to install an XY.appx from my Launcher app? (Launcher detects an xy.appx on a USB stick and installs this app).

No. You could only detect ".appx" files from the USB stick, but you could not install it by your "Launcher".

> 2.) If my Launcher app is a UWP UI app, it would be possible to start another application (already installed one) by URI activation. As far as I understand, this is only possible as UI app (not as background service)?

If the the app has registered the protocol, then you could launch it by Uri. See the [Launch an app for results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results#step-1-register-the-protocol-to-be-handled-in-the-app-that-youll-launch-for-results) for more details.

> 3.) Is it possible to close another app out of my Launcher app? (I guess no, but it would be nice, if the launcher could kill what was started by the Launcher app).

No. You could not close another app from your app. UWP doesn't support it.

> 4.) If the Launcher app is a UI app and would start another UI app, then the Launcher app gets suspended. Is there any possibility to get any app to app communication between a background service (or my new foreground app) and the suspended Launcher?

Please check my above second question's reply, when you launch the other app, you could get result with returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
I have done some prototyping and can add some additional information to answer some of the questions.

> 1.) Is it possible to install an XY.appx from my Launcher app? (Launcher detects an xy.appx on a USB stick and installs this app).

Yes it is. The App which would like to install another app (by using the .appx) needs to add the capabilities for the PackageManager. [This was described in embedded101](http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/entryid/753)

> 4.) If the Launcher app is a UI app and would start another UI app, then the Launcher app gets suspended. Is there any possibility to get any app to app communication between a background service (or my new foreground app) and the suspended Launcher?

Depending on the implementation. If the Launcher app is a UI app communicating with an AppService it is possible to implement a two-way communication and in this case I would assume (did not yet test it), that also the Launcher app would be activated, if the AppService send a message.